# UglifyJS could not be run in intellij when configuring as a file watcher

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, minify, uglifyjs, file-watcher

I'm trying to configure UglifyJS file watcher in IntelliJ as stated in this link:
[minifying-javacripts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/13.0/minifying-javascript.pdf)
But when I try to modify a javascript file and save it, I get this error:

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've installed uglify-js with the command below:

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

And I can minify 'js' files both from windows command line and IntelliJ's internal terminal windows. But can not configure it as a file watcher properly.
I noticed that 'uglifyjs' file in the 'bin' directory of the 'uglify-js' node module, has no suffix. Then i tried to add a '.bat' suffix to it myself hoping the file watcher could run it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Same problem for me. Have you solved it in between?

Comment: @Benoit Unfortunately not! :(

Answer (score 0):

try to find cmd version of uglifyjs command in this folder:
node_modules.bin\uglifyjs.cmd
and set in File Watcher/Watcher Settings/Programs

Note that install the package global may not work because Intellij may not have authorization to access User/AppData/